# Is $P(AB) = P(B \mid A) P(A)$ an error, or am I misunderstanding something?

Tags: probability, bayesian, conditional-probability

I am currently studying the textbook *In all Likelihood* by Yudi Pawitan. The section **Inverse probability: the Bayesians** of chapter **1.4 The emergence of statistics** says the following:

> The simplest form of the Bayes theorem for two events $A$ and $B$ is
> $$P(A \mid B) = \dfrac{P(AB)}{P(B)} = \dfrac{P(B \mid A)P(A)}{P(B \mid A) P(A) + P(B \mid \bar{A})P(\bar{A})} \tag{1.1}$$

I don't think $P(AB) = P(B \mid A) P(A)$ is correct? Is $P(AB) = P(B \mid A) P(A)$ an error, or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: Are $A$ and $B$ events or variables? How do you interpret $AB$?

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus It says "two events $A$ and $B$" right there.

Comment: So what does $AB$ mean if $A$ and $B$ are events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Conditional probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability) is defined as

$$
P(A|B) = \frac{P(A,B)}{P(B)}
$$

$P(A,B) = P(A|B) P(B)$ is just multiplying both sides by $P(B)$. This is what they use. Also notice that when $A$ and $B$ are binary $P(A,B) = P(AB)$, since $AB=1$ only when both $A$ and $B$ are equal to $1$, so maybe they just made a shortcut here.

Comment: Yes, so I guess you're confirming that it's an error/typo; $P(AB)$ is not the same thing as $P(A, B)$.

Comment: @ThePointer see also the edit.

Comment: @ThePointer in most literature, $P(AB)$ is equivalent to $P(A, B)$ or $P(A \cap B)$. In this context I do not think there is a typo.

Comment: @zd_ “most literature” is an overstatement, maybe “some” but it's definitely not the most popular notation.

Comment: @Tim haha ok, I stand corrected. But I think a substantial proportion of literature out there uses this notation, or at least that's the case in probability theory.  Think this notation comes from probability being the expectation of indicators, and joint probability is the expectation of the product of indicators.